# Does the Go language have function/method overloading?

Tags: go, overloading

I'm porting a C library to Go. A C function (with varargs) is defined like this:

```
curl_easy_setopt(CURL *curl, CURLoption option, ...);
```

So I created wrapper C functions:

```
curl_wrapper_easy_setopt_str(CURL *curl, CURLoption option, char* param);
curl_wrapper_easy_setopt_long(CURL *curl, CURLoption option, long param);
```

If I define function in Go like this:

```
func (e *Easy)SetOption(option Option, param string) {
    e.code = Code(C.curl_wrapper_easy_setopt_str(e.curl, C.CURLoption(option), C.CString(param)))
}

func (e *Easy)SetOption(option Option, param long) {
    e.code = Code(C.curl_wrapper_easy_setopt_long(e.curl, C.CURLoption(option), C.long(param)))
}
```

The Go compiler complains:

```
*Easy·SetOption redeclared in this block
```

So does Go support function (method) overloading, or does this error mean something else?

Answer (score 238, accepted):

No it does not.

See the [Go Language FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html), and specifically the section on [overloading](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#overloading).

> Method dispatch is simplified if it doesn't need to do type matching as well. Experience with other languages told us that having a variety of methods with the same name but different signatures was occasionally useful but that it could also be confusing and fragile in practice. Matching only by name and requiring consistency in the types was a major simplifying decision in Go's type system.

Update: 2016-04-07

While Go still does not have overloaded functions (and probably never will), the most useful feature of overloading, that of calling a function with optional arguments and inferring defaults for those omitted can be simulated using a variadic function, which has since been added. But this comes at the loss of type checking.

Comment: "was occasionally useful"? what if I want to write a function that sums numbers? that can accept two arguments of int32, int64, uint32, uint64 and strings? In JS, which does not allow overloading, I could use "number" type, but in strictly typed language like Go I must write tons of functions with slightly different names :/

Comment: @VityaSchel  Well, to be fair, JS doesn't have int32 ... uint64; it has only one intrinsic numeric type, `number` -- so that's apples and oranges. And you wouldn't write tons, you'd just write the (uint64,uint64) function and allow the system to widen them, while converting Strings to uint64 at the call point.

Comment: Has anyone created a `go generate` tool for `playerParams` as advocated in the changelog.ca article?

Answer (score 31):

According to this, it doesn't: http://golang.org/doc/go_for_cpp_programmers.html

In the **Conceptual Differences** section, it says:

> Go does not support function overloading and does not support user defined operators.

Answer (score 16):

**No, Go doesn't have overloading.**

Overloading adds compiler complexity and will likely never be added.

As Lawrence Dol mentioned, you could use a variadic function at the cost of no type checking.

Your best bet is to use **generics** and **type constraints** that were added in **[Go 1.18](https://go.dev/blog/go1.18)**

To answer VityaSchel's question, in the comments of Lawrence's answer, of how to make a generic sum function, I've written one below.

https://go.dev/play/p/hRhInhsAJFT

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Number interface {
  int | int8 | int16 | int32 | int64 | uint | uint8 | uint16 | uint32 | uint64 | float32 | float64
}

func Sum[number Number](a number, b number) number {
  return a + b
}

func main() {
  var a float64 = 5.1
  var b float64 = 3.2
  println(Sum(a, b))

  var a2 int = 5
  var b2 int = 3
  println(Sum(a2, b2))
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Even though this question is really old, what I still want to say is that there is a way to acheive something close to overloading functions. Although it may not make the code so easy to read.

Say if you want to overload the funtion `Test()`:

```golang
func Test(a int) {
    println(a);
}
func Test(a int, b string) {
    println(a);
    println(b);
}
```

The code above will cause error. However if you redefine the first `Test()` to `Test1()` and the second to `Test2()`, and define a new function `Test()` using go's `...`, you would be able to call the function `Test()` the way it is overloaded.
code:

```golang
package main;

func Test1(a int) {
    println(a);
}
func Test2(a int, b string) {
    println(a);
    println(b);
}
func Test(a int, bs ...string) {
    if len(bs) == 0 {
        Test1(a);
    } else {
        Test2(a, bs[0]);
    }
}
func main() {
    Test(1);
    Test(1, "aaa");
}
```

output:

```
1
1
aaa
```

see more at: https://golangbyexample.com/function-method-overloading-golang/ (I'm not the author of this linked article but personally consider it useful)

Comment: this is ugleeeee

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik It _is_, lol

Comment: since we are talking "ugly", I suggest you try function overloading via "dummy" receiver parameters. I suppose overloading for receivers is allowed since otherwise it would be impossible to have interfaces. Just for the sake of experiment. I can't see how it would improve anything

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik You mean something like this? https://go.dev/play/p/CoDbx9cPUY2 It looks fine but you'd probably need to define a large number of types when there is a lot of function overloading required, which could make the typenames quite long and "ugly"

Comment: I'm shocked that it's has so many upvotes, newcomers to Golang can think that it's ok and use this snippet in real life projects :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by making the function variadic using `...interface{}`, this will make the `param` as of type Slice,
and then just take off the first value in it using `param[0]`

```
func (e *Easy)SetOption(option Option, param ...interface{}) {
    e.code = Code(C.curl_wrapper_easy_setopt_str(e.curl, C.CURLoption(option), C.CString(param[0])))
}
```

now argument of any type is valid, but at the cost of type checking