# Default value in Go's method

Tags: go, default-value, function-call, default-arguments

Is there a way to specify default value in Go's function? I am trying to find this in the documentation but I can't find anything that specifies that this is even possible.

```
func SaySomething(i string = "Hello")(string){
...
}
```

Answer (score 180, accepted):

No, the powers that be at Google chose not to support that.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/-5MCaivW0qQ

Comment: Also [this discussion with official statement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/3Go3gPNIPaw/Pv2B5udjDgMJ) and [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032149/optional-parameters).

Answer (score 260):

NO,but there are some other options to implement default value.  There are some [good blog posts](https://joneisen.me/programming/2013/06/23/golang-and-default-values.html) on the subject, but here are some specific examples.

**Option 1:** The caller chooses to use default values

```
// Both parameters are optional, use empty string for default value
func Concat1(a string, b int) string {
  if a == "" {
    a = "default-a"
  }
  if b == 0 {
    b = 5
  }

  return fmt.Sprintf("%s%d", a, b)
}
```

**Option 2:** A single optional parameter at the end

```
// a is required, b is optional.
// Only the first value in b_optional will be used.
func Concat2(a string, b_optional ...int) string {
  b := 5
  if len(b_optional) > 0 {
    b = b_optional[0]
  }

  return fmt.Sprintf("%s%d", a, b)
}
```

**Option 3:** A config struct

```
// A declarative default value syntax
// Empty values will be replaced with defaults
type Parameters struct {
  A string `default:"default-a"` // this only works with strings
  B string // default is 5
}

func Concat3(prm Parameters) string {
  typ := reflect.TypeOf(prm)

  if prm.A == "" {
    f, _ := typ.FieldByName("A")
    prm.A = f.Tag.Get("default")
  }

  if prm.B == 0 {
    prm.B = 5
  }

  return fmt.Sprintf("%s%d", prm.A, prm.B)
}
```

**Option 4:** Full variadic argument parsing (javascript style)

```
func Concat4(args ...interface{}) string {
  a := "default-a"
  b := 5

  for _, arg := range args {
    switch t := arg.(type) {
      case string:
        a = t
      case int:
        b = t
      default:
        panic("Unknown argument")
    }
  }

  return fmt.Sprintf("%s%d", a, b)
}
```

Comment: What a pain. I wish it was: `func Concat1(a string = 'foo', b int = 10) string {` like in most other modern languages... It would reduce any of the given examples pretty much to one line of code.

Comment: Do we have an option of writing two different functions and leave it to the caller to be explicit about what they expect.

Comment: @ProgramCpp no, golang doesn't allow function overloading [Does the Go language have function/method overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986944/does-the-go-language-have-function-method-overloading)

Comment: Default values are tricky, when you have a caller that omits the value - you never know if the value they want was "default at the moment of implementation" or "default at any point in the future" - it makes the code intent less obvious. Go making it painful might not be as bad as you think.

Comment: The lack of default parameter values, and named parameters, is yet another shortcoming of Go.

Answer (score 18):

No, there is no way to specify defaults. I believer this is done on purpose to enhance readability, at the cost of a little more time (and, hopefully, thought) on the writer's end.

I think the proper approach to having a "default" is to have a new function which supplies that default to the more generic function. Having this, your code becomes clearer on your intent. For example:

```
func SaySomething(say string) {
    // All the complicated bits involved in saying something
}

func SayHello() {
    SaySomething("Hello")
}
```

With very little effort, I made a function that does a common thing and reused the generic function. You can see this in many libraries, `fmt.Println` for example just adds a newline to what `fmt.Print` would otherwise do. When reading someone's code, however, it is clear what they intend to do by the function they call. With default values, I won't know what is supposed to be happening without also going to the function to reference what the default value actually is.

Comment: I like and agree with this answer but damn do I still wish they at least had an obtuse but idiomatic way of doing it.

Comment: The _"just add another function"_ argument can result in an explosion of methods required to deal with multiple permutations, requires the burden of deciding on meaningful, discoverable and rememberable names for those methods, and adds burden to learning the packages that use more methods vs. less. #jmtcw

Comment: Well, as someone who has had to untangle mountains of source code 10-20years later to find bugs to support customers, I think additional function names might have some benefit

Comment: There’s a gap between "this approach might have some benefit" and "let's design the language so that this approach is the only possible one (even where it doesn’t make sense)".

Answer (score 4):

A default function argument usually provides the client code with a very common argument value while still allowing the client code to override it. A similar result can be achieved by turning the function into a method of a struct and the default argument into a field of that struct.

Let's see it with a function based on your example (it doesn't compile):

```
func SaySomething(msg string = "Hello") string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("I say %q", msg)
}
```

First, define a struct that will hold the default argument:

```
type SomethingSayer struct {
    msg string
}
```

Second, turn the function `SaySomething` into a method on the struct `SomethingSayer`. The original function parameter `msg` is replaced by `s.msg`, a `SomethingSayer`'s field:

```
func (s SomethingSayer) SaySomething() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("I say %q", s.msg)
}
```

You can also define a constructor for the `SomethingSayer` struct. This will set the field `msg` with the original default argument:

```
func NewSaySomethingSayer() SomethingSayer {
    return SomethingSayer {
        msg: "Hello", // the default argument
    }
}
```

Finally, define a convenience wrapping function that is like the original one but without the parameter that had the default argument:

```
func SaySomething() string {
    return NewSaySomethingSayer().SaySomething()
}
```

This way, the client code can just call `SaySomething()` when the defaults are suitable. If that's not the case, it can still construct its own `SomethingSayer` and then call the `SaySomething()` method:

```
fmt.Println(SaySomething())    // I say "Hello"

s := SomethingSayer {
    msg: "Bye",
}
fmt.Println(s.SaySomething())  // I say "Bye"
```

Note that this approach is also followed by the standard library in [`http.Get`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Get), [`http.Head`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Head), and [`http.Post`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Post). That is, this function allows you to perform a GET request without explicitly constructing a [`http.Client`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client): it uses a globally available `http.Client` value ([`http.DefaultClient`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.4:src/net/http/client.go;l=109)) and calls its [`Get`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client.Get) method on it. Similarly, client code can still override the default arguments (e.g., the timeout) by constructing its own `http.Client` and calling `Get` on it.