# Function Overloading in golang

Tags: struct, go, overloading

I am not sure if this is the right term for this scenario.

I have a struct defined in a package, with a variable defined as type string, and I have a setter method to set the value of that variable. However, I cannot be sure of the type of value that could be passed to that method. It could be an int or a string. Is there a concept that is similar to java, where I can write the same function twice, but with different parameters, so that I don't have to do a type checking before populating the struct?

Comment: No overloading in Go, well explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986944

Comment: No there is not. You need two functions, but then you don't need type checking. Stop thinking Java.

Comment: Well, *strictly* speaking, there isn't. To reduce redundant code however, you can accept an interface and do a [type switch](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch).