# Optional arguments?

Tags: function, go, optional-arguments

Is there a way to declare an argument as "optional" in the Go programming language?

Example of what I mean:

```
func doSomething(foo string, bar int) bool {
    //...
}
```

I want the parameter `bar` to be optional and default to `0` if nothing is passed through.

```
doSomething("foo")
```

would be the same as

```
doSomething("foo",0)
```

I'm unable to find anything about this matter in the [official documentation about functions](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Function_declarations).

Comment: its not supported as a design decision, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032149/optional-parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe Go does support optional arguments to functions, though you can fake it with [variadic functions](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters). The C approach, if you don't want to do that, is to pretend the language supports currying:

```
func doSomethingNormally(foo string) bool {
    doSomething(foo, 0)
}
```

Comment: it's pretty sad that there's no integrated support for optional arguments in Go. I solved my problem by using a variadic function. Thank you.

Comment: Mainstream languages like C, Java, C++ don't support optional args neither, AFAICS.

Comment: @jnml, C++ can fake it with overloaded function prototypes. Many mainstream languages, like Python, do support default values for function parameters. That's actually what we're talking about since I think all of those (I don't know Java) and certainly most mainstream languages do support variadic functions.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fake it is to pass a struct.

```
type dsArgs struct {
    foo string
    bar int
}

func doSomething(fb dsArgs) bool {
    //...
}
```

Then

```
doSomething(dsArgs{foo: "foo"})
```

is the same as

```
doSomething(dsArgs{foo: "foo", bar: 0})
```

Comment: I like this approach, but what about when the default value for bar needs to be something other than zero, and likewise the default value for foo is some arbitrary string? I get a bit irritated with Go when I can't find simple ways to resolve cases like this.