# Built-In source code location

Tags: go

Where in Go's source code can I find their implementation of `make`.

Turns out the "code search" functionality is almost useless for such a central feature of the language, and I have no good way to determine if I should be searching for a C function, a Go function, or what.

Also in the future how do I figure out this sort of thing without resorting to asking here? (i.e.: teach me to fish)

**EDIT**
P.S. I already found http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make, but that, unlike the rest of the go packages, doesn't include a link to the source, presumably because it's somewhere deep in compiler-land.

Comment: I don't care much about the lost reputation, but as a brief defense: reading code in order to understand the programming tools you're using is a central part of being a good programmer. This question concerns "software tools commonly used by programmers" and is a "practical, answerable problem unique to the programming profession".  A lack of source code does not automatically invalidate a question, especially when I'm *looking* for source code to begin with. This is an on-topic, non-subjective question.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There is no `make()` as such. Simply put, this is happening:

1. go code: `make(chan int)`
2. symbol substitution: `OMAKE`
3. symbol typechecking: `OMAKECHAN`
4. code generation: `runtime·makechan`

`gc`, which is a go flavoured C parser, parses the `make` call according to context (for easier type checking).

This conversion is done in [cmd/compile/internal/gc/typecheck.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.10/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/typecheck.go#L1831).

After that, depending on what symbol there is (e.g., `OMAKECHAN` for `make(chan ...)`),
the appropriate runtime call is substituted in [cmd/compile/internal/gc/walk.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.10/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/walk.go#L1417). In case of `OMAKECHAN` this would be `makechan64` or `makechan`.

Finally, when running the code, said substituted function [in pkg/runtime](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.10/src/runtime/chan.go#L70) is called.

#### How do you find this

I tend to find such things mostly by imagining in which stage of the process this
particular thing may happen. In case of `make`, with the knowledge that there's no
definition of `make` in `pkg/runtime` (the most basic package), it has to be on compiler level
and is likely to be substituted to something else.

You then have to search the various compiler stages (gc, *g, *l) and in time you'll find
the definitions.

Answer (score 18):

As a matter of fact `make` is a combination of different functions, implemented in Go, in the runtime.

- [makeslice](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/slice.go#L39) for e.g. `make([]int, 10)`
- [makemap](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/hashmap.go#L190) for e.g. `make(map[string]int)`
- [makechan](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/chan.go#L56) for e.g. `make(chan int)`

The same applies for the other built-ins like `append` and `copy`.