# How to extract go builtin function code such as delete()

Tags: go

I have found the builtin function in go src (/go/src/builtin/builtin.go), as following:

```
func delete(m map[Type]Type1, key Type)
```

But this is not source code. Who can tell me where is the builtin function source code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Built-In source code location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512781/built-in-source-code-location)

Comment: @CodingPickle: I wasn't going to mark it as such, since that links to the old repo and old C based compiler. However, my answer will eventually be obsolete too -- so I guess that makes this question "off topic".

Answer (score 7):

[`builtin.go`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/) is simply a file for documentation purposes. It doesn't contain any implementations.

The map implementation is in [`runtime/map.go`](https://go.dev/src/runtime/map.go). The delete functionality is implemented in the `mapdelete` function.