# Golang's builtin function implementations

Tags: go

I am unable to find the implementation of built-in functions.

In builtin.go, this is what I found:

```
// The copy built-in function copies elements from a source slice 
into a
// destination slice. (As a special case, it also will copy bytes 
from a
// string to a slice of bytes.) The source and destination may 
overlap. Copy
// returns the number of elements copied, which will be the minimum 
of
// len(src) and len(dst).
func copy(dst, src []Type) int
```

Where is the actual implementation of the built-in functions?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/34614794? Anyway, short answer is "in the runtime code", look there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract go builtin function code?such as delete()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614794/how-to-extract-go-builtin-function-codesuch-as-delete)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Built-In source code location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512781/built-in-source-code-location)

Answer (score 2):

The [builtin](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin) package serves as documentation only.  The package does not contain implementations of the functions.

The builtin functions are implemented by a combination of the compiler and functions internal to the [runtime](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime) package.

You can find the low-level implementation of copy in the  memmove* files in the [runtime source directory](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src/runtime)
.