# Better way to deal with arguments in my golang variadic function

Tags: go, variadic-functions

Is there a shorter way to initialize `ip2` to empty string if there is only one argument in my variadic function below?

```
func myvariadic(ip ...string) {
    ip1 := ip[0]
    if len(ip) > 1 { 
        ip2 := ip[1] 
    } else {
        ip2 := ""
        ///...
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may simply use:

```
func myvariadic(ip ...string) {
    ip1, ip2 := ip[0], ""
    if len(ip) > 1 {
        ip2 = ip[1]
    }
    fmt.Println(ip1, ip2)
}
```

But don't forget that variadic functions may be called with 0 arguments specified / passed as the value for the variadic parameter. What this means is that it is also legal (not a compile-time error) to call `myvariadic()` with zero arguments, and then even `ip[0]` will cause a runtime panic.

If your function must receive at least one string and optionally a second, you should change the signature of your function to this:

```
func myvariadic(ip1 string, ips ...string) {
    ip2 := ""
    if len(ips) > 1 {
        ip2 = ips[1]
    }
    fmt.Println(ip1, ip2)
}
```

What this guarantees is that 1 `string` will surely be passed (else it would be a compile-time error). This is also more efficient if only one argument is passed, as no slice allocation will be needed (`nil` will be used for `ips`). See more details on this here: [Is it possible to trigger compile time error with custom library in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270743/is-it-possible-to-trigger-compile-time-error-with-custom-library-in-golang/37271129#37271129)

If parameters are always 1 or 2 `string` values, I'm not sure variadic parameters is justified at all, you may simply use:

```
func myNonVariadic(ip1, ip2 string) {
    fmt.Println(ip1, ip2)
}
```

And simply pass the empty string `""` at the caller if `ip2` is not available.

If you still want to stick to variadic function, another option would be to not introduce `ip1` and `ip2` inside the function, but simply use `ip[0]` and `ip[1]`. And to avoid runtime panic if less than 2 arguments is passed, you may append an empty string yourself, e.g.:

```
func myvariadic(ip ...string) {
    if len(ip) < 2 {
        ip = append(ip, "")
    }
    fmt.Println(ip[0], ip[1])
}
```

And the version that also deals with 0 arguments:

```
func myvariadic(ip ...string) {
    for len(ip) < 2 {
        ip = append(ip, "")
    }
    fmt.Println(ip[0], ip[1])
}
```

This latter version makes sure the `ip` variable (of slice type) will have at least 2 elements, even if 0 is passed.

Answer (score 2):

Declare all locals up front and remove `else`. This is the only other way I could think of:

```
func myvariadic(ip ...string) {
    ip1 := ip[0]
    var ip2 string
    if len(ip) > 1 { 
        ip2 = ip[1] 
    }

    fmt.Println(ip1,ip2)
```

Comment: Remove the `:` in `ip2 :=` else you'll be creating a variable with the same name in an inner scope. Good answer otherwise :)

Comment: Yeah.. my bad.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to *initialize* at all.  All primitive types are initialized to their default values in Go.

IOW, this is true.

```
a := ""
var b string
fmt.Println(a == b)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/hwQmU4Myrp

Therefore, you inferred assignment of `ip2 := ""` is already the most succinct version you can type.

Comment: But the problem is that I will get 'out of index' in myvariadic func in case of more than 1 argument because ip[1] will not exists