# Abstraction patterns in go

Tags: go, interface, abstraction

I have two interfaces. They are almost the same, the only difference is the `Set` method:

```
type Cache1 interface {
    Set(key, value interface{}, ttl time.Duration) bool
}

type Cache2 interface {
    Set(key, value interface{}) bool
}
```

Any idea how to unite them into one abstraction? Surely I can add `ttl time.Duration` to the second interface, but it will useless there and will worsen code readability. Could you please suggest sophisticated pattern if such exist?

Comment: There's no way to answer this question. The proper solution depends on countless variables. How are you using these interfaces? Why do they need to be the same interface in the first place? How are they used? Should `Set` even be part of the interface? Etc etc. Without an intimate understanding of your application, there's no way to answer this.

Comment: Do you want to keep both methods? Or you want a single, merged `Set()` method?

Comment: @icza, I want single but flexible method

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ Then that comes down to [Optional Parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032149/optional-parameters)

Comment: Answered my own question, could you please review?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, you should care of interface segregation principle while merging those methods.

Technically, you are able to merge them by wrapping all arguments to `SetRequest` or something.
Interface will be sort of

```
type Cache interface {
    Set(request SetRequest) bool
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another opportunity just came in mind is unite interfaces into one:

```
type Cache interface {
    Set(key, value interface{}, ttl time.Duration) bool
}
```

And ignore redundant argument in method signature if necessary:

```
func (c *cache) Set(key, value interface{}, _ time.Duration) bool {
```